# openai module not found but can be clicked while importing in ide to go to its library

Tags: python, django, openai-api

I am trying to create a chat bot with openai on django.

But it shows that it doesnt exist in the IDE. I click on 'openai' and it takes me to its library.
When i type "**pip show openai**" , it gives :

```
Name: openai
Version: 0.27.7
Summary: Python client library for the OpenAI API
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: support@openai.com
License: 
Location: /Users/user/PROJECTS/chatbot_project/env_chat/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, tqdm, requests
Required-by:
```

the python and pip have version 3.9

i dont understand that if i am able to click on the 'openai' while importing it and it dont even red underline it so why it tells the module dont exist.

```
import openai
```

my python interpreter is linked with the env i created in the project i.e. **env_chat**

i am a bit new, so help me out on this.

Comment: temporarily fixed it by adding import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/virtual/environment/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages') , any suggestion what should i read or search to get it fixed globally so that such problem dont occur again with other modules.